# Python - how to create a function, that can access to variables inside loop in another function? All are inside the same class

Tags: python-3.x, function, loops, class

I have 3 functions, that do something. I want to create next, that will show results based on previous functions. I have a problem, because one functions have for loop, and I can't obtain that data inside the 4th function. What can I do?

I can't paste the full code, but I try to prepare a good example. I create only important things, but this everything is inside class.

```
def perm(self):
some loop based on variable combos ...

for item in combos:
    # Random 100 numbers. 
    
    self.a = some str with char "?" in every word at specific position.
    self.b = some str with char "!" in every word at specific position.

    # So I have in total 200 numbers, because 100 have "?", and 100 have "!" at             
    # specific position, always on the same position.
    # Example: self.a[0] 13!24!35 self.b[0] 13?24?35
    # and so on with all.

def template(self):
# Here I have some template based on for loop above.
# And now this code not work good, because self.tmp can print only the last 
# pattern remembered by self.a and self.b, because here isn't any loop. 

self.tmp = f'A: {self.a} B: {self.b}' 
# So print(self.tmp) give me only 1 result (the last self.a and self.b 
# from the loop) instead of 100 results.
```

Ok, so how can I beat this? I tried lots of options provided by itertools, concatenating, appending, various other combinations and all ends failure.
Theoretically I can beat this very easy (check below), but in my opinion that option is not good. I have functions, and every do something. For example, one generate something, second create something based on previous function, another do xyz and so on. I want to keep it separately. I heard, this is the best practice in programming, because all is clear. But as I say, I can do this:

```
def perm(self):
    some loop based on variable combos ...

for item in combos:
    # Random 100 numbers. 
    
    self.a = some str with char "?" in every word at specific position.
    self.b = some str with char "!" in every word at specific position.

    # So here I have my function, and script will be work very well,
    # but I hear it's not professional. Better way is creating the new function for 
    # result, instead of combining it.
    
    self.template()
```

The next option is very similar to the previous.I can create function in function, so theoretically all are clear:

```
def perm(self):
    some loop based on variable combos ...

for item in combos:
    # Random 100 numbers. 

    self.a = some str with char "?" in every word at specific position.
    self.b = some str with char "!" in every word at specific position.

    # So I create function in function with specific name, and I know what it
    # can do, but it's function inside function.

    def results():
        self.template()
    results()
```

But maybe exist a better way to obtain what I want? I think, I want something like this:

```
def result(self):
# in some way access each numbers from for item in combos:
self.template()

# In that case, I have function only for show me results based 
# on a few functions
```

Sorry if any language mistakes exist, English is not my main language. In my country is middle of the night right now, I'm very sleepy. Thanks for any answers.

Comment: Is your issue that you cannot access `combos` in `result()`?

Comment: I think you should provide a [example]. It's difficult to understand what you are trying to do.